# Image of open set is open if derivative is nonsingular and function is $C^1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am trying to show that if $A$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is of class $C^1$, and $Df(x)$ is nonsingular for all $x\in A$, then the image of $A$, $f(A)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I am not sure how I should approach this. Any hints?

Comment: Hint: If $Df(x)$ is nonsingular, then $f$ has a local inverse which is continuous by the Inverse function theorem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

The inverse function theorem states that $f^{-1}$ exists locally and is also $C^1$.